# How to Customize slide bar using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created slider which appears on top of html page but i need it to appear at the bottom and also the horizontal slide bar 
should be reduced to half of its size and also I want to limit the value from (0-100) to (min:1-max:25)
I am new to the css and I don't know how to do this can someone help me please.I have also uploaded the complete code.

```js
$(function() {
  var handle = $("#custom-handle");
  $("#slider").slider({
    create: function() {
      handle.text($(this).slider("value"));
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      handle.text(ui.value);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#custom-handle {
  width: 3em;
  height: 1.6em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.8em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="slider">
  <div id="custom-handle" class="ui-slider-handle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: to set min/max value, just add those properties when you create your slide...check the [docs](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the minimum and maximum for the slider you would do this:

```
$(function() {
  var handle = $("#custom-handle");
  $("#slider").slider({
    min: 1,               //<--------Min
    max: 25,              //<-------Max
create: function() {
  handle.text($(this).slider("value"));
},
slide: function(event, ui) {
  handle.text(ui.value);
}
  });
});
```

for the CSS, you could position it like this:

```
#slider {
  width:50%; /*make it half its width*/
  position:absolute; /*allow you to position it at the bottom*/
  bottom:20px; /*how far from the bottom*/
  left:20px; /* how far from the left*/
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3t0s597v/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, everything you need!

```js
$(function() {
  var handle = $("#custom-handle");
  $("#slider").slider({
 min: 1, 
max: 25, 
    create: function() {
      handle.text($(this).slider("value"))
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      handle.text(ui.value);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#custom-handle {
  width: 3em;
  height: 1.6em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.8em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}

#slider {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="slider">
  <div id="custom-handle" class="ui-slider-handle"></div>
</div>
```